# Problema con un bucle

Tags: java, backend

Resulta que estoy realizando un bucle en el que tienes que meter un nombre y el bucle tiene como condición que no se salga mientras haya caracteres vacíos. El problema es que no se me sale del bucle aunque meta caracteres. Y no encuentro la forma de poder solucionarlo.

```java
System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre:");
                    do {
                        p1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
                    }while(p1.getNombre()!= null);
```

Comment: Probé a usarlo como dices, con while(p1.getNombre()==null) pero cuando lo hago y doy a un enter para comprobar que no se salga del bucle hasta que no haya algun caracter, se sale del bucle.

Comment: No solo "null" no significa "espacios vacíos", si no que `null` no es ni siquiera un string. El método `nextLine()` no devuelve `null` si no pones nada (si no me equivoco), devuelve un String vacío -> `""`. No es para nada lo mismo :) Debes usar `p1.getNombre().equals("")` para comprobar si está vacío o no

Comment: @Benito-B Muchas gracias ese era mi fallo, estoy empezando en programación y todavía no conozco muy bien los conceptos.

Comment: No te preocupes, no nacemos aprendidos. *El único ignorante es el que se niega a aprender* :)

Comment: No había leido el comentario donde respondían, pero bueno. De igual manera ahí dejé mi aporte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código, y lo que requieren sugiero lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre:");
do {
    p1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
} while(p1.getNombre() == null || p1.getNombre().trim().isEmpty());
```

Lo que hacemos es hacer que el bucle se repita si no se ingresa información, como no se si al no ingresar info se almacena es vacío o nulo, hago la comparación tanto con el nulo como con el vacío.

Con el `trim()` lo que hacemos es borrar los espacios en blanco tanto en el lado izquierdo con en la derecha del texto, esto con el fin de que si se ingresan solo espacios la cadena quee vacía sin espacios.

Tambien puedes cambiar el `isEmpty()` por el `equals("")`

Espero te sirva,

Saludos

Comment: Lo bueno de usar equals es que te evitas el null check. `while(!"".equals(p1.getNombre()))` Es decir, si p1 es null, es diferente de `""` :)